# Can't return a string from a Fetch function in JavaScript in html tag

Tags: javascript, function, fetch-api

I'm looking to return a string in a html tag. (Chuck Norris joke from an API)
I succeed to display the value if I ask directly to display it in the function body.

But I don't succeed to return a string to display it later. I want to call only once the function so I can display the string in several areas.

What is working:

```
document.querySelector('#bt_funFact').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  norrisRandom();
})

async function norrisRandom() {
  fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data.value)
      document.getElementById('funFact').innerHTML = data.value;
    })
}
```

But if I try to return the value like below, I get "[object Promise]" in html.

```
document.querySelector('#bt_funFact').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  document.getElementById('funFact').innerHTML = norrisRandom();
})

async function norrisRandom() {
  fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data.value)
      return data.value;
    })
}
```

I can't figure out why it displays in function body and not by returning the value.

Comment: Since it's declared `async`, it returns a `Promise`. You have to use `await` or `.then()`

Comment: `.innerHTML = await norrisRandom();`

Comment: Not much purpose to declare a function `async` when you're not going to use `await` inside of it.

Comment: no return in your norrisRandom function. no await when you call norrisRandom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing is because the norrisRandom() function is asynchronous and returns a promise. When you try to set the innerHTML directly with norrisRandom(), you are assigning the promise object to it, which is why you see "[object Promise]" in the HTML. Try this

```js
document.querySelector('#bt_funFact').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const joke = await norrisRandom();
  document.getElementById('funFact').innerHTML = joke;
});

async function norrisRandom() {
  const response = await fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random');
  const data = await response.json();
  return data.value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Even way more simple that what I started !
But is it mandatory to use const joke, I can't write directly :
document.getElementById('funFact').innerHTML = await norrisRandom(); ?

Comment: @Macronaute No, it is not required. You can directly replace `joke` with the value of the expression assigned to it.

Answer (score 1):

The event listener should use `await` to extract the value from the promise returned by `norrisRandom()`. Your code is putting the Promise itself in the inner HTML.

`norrisRandom()` doesn't need to be declared `async`, since `.then()` returns a promise already. But you need to return the value of the `.then()` chain.

```
document.querySelector('#bt_funFact').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  document.getElementById('funFact').innerHTML = await norrisRandom();
})

function norrisRandom() {
  return fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data.value)
      return data.value;
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but even adding await before function calling returns 'undefined' value in html :/
Effectively, I was not aware that 'then()' was retourning promise already. Thanks !

Comment: Did you add `return` before `fetch`?

Comment: Sorry @barmar I missed this point !

Answer (score -1):

You don't seem to understand what the `async` keyword is doing, so:

Declaring a function async makes it possible to use `await` inside of it.

This makes it possible to write asynchronous code in a synchronous fashion:

```js
async function fn() {
    await one()
    await two()
    await three()
    console.log("done!")
}
```

Is functionally equivalent to:

```
function fn() {
    return one()
        .then(() => {
            return two()
        })
        .then(() => {
            return three()
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log("done!")
        })
}
```

Notice how the `async` function is much easier to read?

So there's no point in declaring a function `async` when you're not going to use the `await` keyword inside of it!

Let's start by fixing your `norrisRandom` function:

```js
async function norrisRandom() {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
  const data = await res.json()

  return data.value  
}
```

Then use `await` **inside** your click handler like this:

```js
document.querySelector('#bt_funFact').addEventListener('click', async () => {
    document.getElementById('funFact').innerHTML = await norrisRandom();
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it's way more clear with your example !

Comment: `async` is generally used to make your code more readable so in most cases there won't be a need to use `.then()` inside an `async` function - that's what `await` is used for. And you're welcome! :)